# Settings does not exist in the current context error

Tags: c#, settings

I am reading a code from an article on Abstract patterns in wikipedia and there is this code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var appearance = Settings.Appearance;//What is THIS??

            IGUIFactory factory;
            switch (appearance)
            {
                case Appearance.Win:
                    factory = new WinFactory();
                    break;
                case Appearance.OSX:
                    factory = new OSXFactory();
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new System.NotImplementedException();
            }

            var button = factory.CreateButton();
            button.Paint();

        }
```

I can't find what this *Settings* refer to. (And obviously the name Settings does not exist in the current context)

At first I thought it refered to `Properties.Settings` (which I have used before) but then I found there are no settings in a Console application (only in Winforms)

Can anybody refresh me about this?

Comment: Settings is probably settings file added to project.

Comment: In Visual Studio right click on a project name in Solution Explorer -> Properties -> Settings. That's where you can add Settings to any project kind.

Comment: probably setting is a class (sample class) in project that have a property with name Appearance, error (Settings does not exist in the current context error
) is  compiler error and means that Setting class do be defined .